# How to avoid syn cookies

Tags: linux, kernel

I've got a (TCP) server that handles a big number of new connections per second (1000 - 5000). This causes syn cookies to be send:

```
kernel: possible SYN flooding on port 2710. Sending cookies.
```

Syn cookies aren't that bad (in this case), but how do I avoid this. What app or kernel knobs can I turn? Documentation on this appears to be very scarce.
The kernel is Linux 2.6.32 x64.

Comment: SYN cookies! Om nom nom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syncookies is controlled by the setting in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies`, which you may read the [document exist in Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) for more details. To be specific, here's the part which I think is relevant:

> ```
>     Note, that syncookies is fallback facility.
>     It MUST NOT be used to help highly loaded servers to stand
>     against legal connection rate. If you see SYN flood warnings
>     in your logs, but investigation shows that they occur
>     because of overload with legal connections, you should tune
>     another parameters until this warning disappear.
>     See: tcp_max_syn_backlog, tcp_synack_retries, tcp_abort_on_overflow.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So should I increase tcp_max_syn_backlog or the somaxconn? I'm not sure how they interact.

Comment: @XTF if I were you, I will try one of them. For example, increase tcp_max_syn_backlog to 7000, to see if it still need to use syncookies or not.