# Automatic TCP SYN - cookie activation

Tags: tcp, kernel, sysctl, flooding, cookie

I am simulating a SYN flood attack on a Raspberry Pi 1 with KALI Linux (ARM) installed.
A similar message as mentioned in this post was printed after performing the attack: [How to avoid syn cookies](https://serverfault.com/q/393053/1046998).

> `kernel: possible SYN flooding on port X. Sending cookies.`

The `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` variable was set to `1` automatically.

Now my problem, is, that it is not possible to disable it anymore. I rewrote the value to 0 with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0`, but when performing the attack again, the kernel message is not shown. Additionally, after rebooting the system, the variable is set back to 1.

My questions would be:

- Is the use of `sysctl -w` directly changing whether SYN - cookies are used for TCP connections (in real time)?
- Why is the variable reset to `1` upon reboot?
- Where can I configure/find the SYN - cookie activation automatism?

I tried disabling the NetworkManager service, resulting in the same behavior after reboot.

Comment: `sysctl` command doesn't make permanent changes, you'll want to read `man sysctl` and `man sysctl.conf`

Comment: By using `sysctl.conf` I could set the variable upon start, thank you. Will the variable force (not) to use syn - cookies, or can the kernel still decide? I am not sure how to check whether the `[SYN,ACK]` packets actually include the cookies (with Wireshark). Are there concrete reference points for this? 


Also, regarding my 3rd question, is there any way of configuring the kernel without `sysctl` or `sysctl.conf` and where can I find the automatism for activating syn - cookies?